# Creating user alert node on User Alert module

Tags: 7

The steps for using the [User Alert](http://drupal.org/project/user_alert) module are the following:

> 1. Enable User Alerts
> 2. Set the appropriate permissions for selected roles
> 3. Set the User Alert block in the appropriate region of your theme.
> 4. Create a user alert node.

How can you create a user alert node in Step 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module defines a "User Alert" content type; when you go to http://example.com/node/add/user_alert (replace example.com with the domain name of your site), you are going to create a node of that content type, if you have the permission to create nodes of that content type.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_info().
 */
function user_alert_node_info() {
  return array(
    'user_alert' => array(
      'name' => t('User Alert'),
      'base' => 'user_alert',
      'description' => t('A User Alert is a short Twitter like message displayed at the top of the site, alerting users to critical information like an online sale, new blog post, or breaking news. After viewing it, they can click and close the message.'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => t('Title'),
      'disabled' => FALSE,
    )
  );
}
```

Check on admin/people/permissions you have at least the "User Alert: Create new content" permission; that is the permission to create nodes of that type. Then, you need the "User Alert: Edit own content" permission to edit the nodes you created.